# MobaXterm selects multiple lines

Tags: selection, mobaxterm

When I try to select text by holding the left click button and moving the mouse in MobaXterm Personal Edition v21.3 build 4736, entire lines or multiple lines are automatically highlighted instead of allowing me to select only a small section of a line.  Is this a bug or a setting that can be changed to revert back to highlighting only the targeted section of a line?  I would have to restart MobaXterm or start a new SSH session to get around this behavior.  Thanks in advance!